# Web Application - Neo4j Database per User

Tags: servlets, graph, neo4j

I have been using neo4j in the context of a Java Servlet web application (Maven web app archetype project). I have a separate MySQL server running which stores user information.

The application needs to provide a separate graph database per each user that needs to be stored  (preferably in the database, as opposed to a folder on the server).

I have used the following code to create a database:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("Neo4j/db");
```

This stores the database in a local directory on the server host. It would be undesirable to 'pollute' the host by making a local graph database for each user (e.g. it would consume host memory for data storage which is naturally a database responsibility). Also, I would prefer if I do not need to configure and run a separate neo4j server.

*Is there some way to keep a neo4j database in memory, serialize it so that the data could be stored in a relational database, and deserialize it when the server needs to use the graph database?*

Comment: You're trying to avoid the overhead of multiple graph databases, by 1) introducing a relational database; 2) dumping an entire neo4j database to a relational database when not in use; and 3) restoring a user-specific database each time it's needed? This doesn't make sense. I'm sure you *can* do any type of serialization you want (meaning the answer is 'yes'), but I just don't see how that's possibly going to scale in the real world...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be nothing preventing you from having a single Neo4j instance, in which you store all users' graphs. If you think you can solve your problem by having multiple graphs, then it means that the users' graphs are disconnected. In that case, if you start a traversal in one graph, it will not reach the other graphs and thus expose other users' data. All you need is a link between the user in your MySQL database and the user node in Neo4j, which you can achieve by, for example, a property called mysqlId on the :User node in Neo.